# One Android app to rule them all? (Alternative options to SSO)

Tags: android, security, single-sign-on

I am working with several organizations. They have formed a coalition and have agreed to share apps they have created. The group is trying to implement a set of Android applications that will be used by first responders on shared devices during a high visibility event.  The applications are all 3rd party, by various vendors, and since the group does not have time to implement an SSO solution, they are using an app called Keeper to allow the users to store their credentials in a database.  This is not an ideal solution, but it’s a time crunch.  The biggest issue that they are looking at right now is that, although they can set Keeper to log out of the Keeper app itself after a set amount of time, the applications that the user was logged into will all remain logged in unless the user manually logs out.  This means that at shift change, unless the first user manually logs out of all of their apps, the second user will have access to all of their applications.

One of the ideas that they had was to create an external Android script that would allow the user to logout of all applications with a single click. But it seems like this would require access to session ID’s and other information from all of the 3rd party applications.  If that were possible, it seems like it would be a scarily large security flaw.

Can anyone shine some light on this for me?

Comment: "This means that at shift change, unless the first user manually logs out of all of their apps, the second user will have access to all of their applications" -- why not give separate OS-level user accounts to each user?

Comment: I kind of understand where you are going but can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: If you have N users, and you use PINs or something so they cannot readily log in as one another, you would appear to achieve your objective without code changes. The app instance that User A was in will be distinct from the app instance started by User B.

Comment: Any idea what the upper bound is for N on a single common device by today's standards?

Comment: Beats me. I haven't tried creating more than a couple. I am not aware of any specific limit.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like neither the Bittium nor the Sonim devices has the “Users” menu.  The Bittium is on Android version 5.1.1 and the Sonim is on 4.4.4, so I thought that they should both have  the feature, but it looks like neither does.